# Pushes blocked from Urbanairship after two pages navigation

Tags: push-notification, urbanairship.com, android-permissions

I am working with Urbanairship services for push notification.
 Before entering into the query I would like to show my app manifest file for reference.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    debuggable="true"
    package="package_name"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="1.3.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="19"
        android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <!-- below permission added for mixpanel api -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <!-- for cloud to device messaging -->
    <permission
        android:name="package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- Required for the Urban Airship library -->
    <permission
        android:name="package_name.permission.UA_DATA"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="package_name.permission.UA_DATA" />

    <!-- Required for Push -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- Required only for location -->
    <!-- Use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION if GPS access is not necessary -->
    <!-- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" / -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- OPTIONAL - This permission is only necessary if your app has multiple processes -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" /> -->

    <application
        android:name=".ShowApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true" >
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DomainActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UploadHome"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FilePickerActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TempMediaPlayer"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareSingleAsset"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UploadResult"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

            <!--
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="package_name.SplashActivity"
                />            -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThumbActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SlideShowActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PreviewActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BecomeaMemberActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DomainExpiredActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MediaPlayerActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareSendAgainActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewShowList"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="*.showontherun.com/"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*.showonthecloud.com/"
                    android:scheme="http" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALL_APPS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowInfoPage"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SupportActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.ViewOfflineShows"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.ViewOfflineThumbActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.ViewOfflinePreviewPage"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.SlideShowOfflineActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iw.sotc.dialog.SaveShowDialogActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.acra.CrashReportDialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/InfoDialog" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.DownloadService" >
        </service>
        <service android:name=".DownloadActivityPreviewActivity" >
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MediaPlayerService" >
        </service>
        <service android:name=".UploadingService" >
        </service>
        <service android:name=".UploadLinkService" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".UploadMedia"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_upload_media"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MediaPlayer"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_media_player" >
        </activity>

        <!--
        added by Karthikeyan V 
        for managing the mixpanel api survey 




        -->
        <activity android:name="com.mixpanel.android.surveys.SurveyActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.AutoCheckForSurveys"
            android:value="false" />

        <!-- added for cloud to Device(C2DM)Messaging service -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="package_name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- < added by siva for play the audio by streaming > -->
        <activity
            android:name=".AudioStream"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>

        <!-- added for mixpanel in-app notification -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.AutoShowMixpanelUpdates"
            android:value="false" />

        <!-- Required for the library -->
        <provider
            android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
            android:authorities="package_name.urbanairship.provider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:permission="package_name.permission.UA_DATA" />

        <!-- Required for Push -->
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="package_name" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Required for detecting when the application is upgraded so it can request a new GCM ID -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

                <data android:scheme="package_name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Required for analytics -->
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService" />

        <!-- Required for Rich Push -->
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService" />

        <!-- Required for Actions -->
        <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionActivity" />

        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService" />

        <!-- Required for Landing Page Action -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName=".ThumbActivity" >

            <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED set or remove the parent activity -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="package_name.ThumbActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="package_name.IntentReceiver" >
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".YoutubeVideoPlayer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_youtube_video_player"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When executing my app, I can receive the APID. When trying to push from Urbanairship web account I had the problem as below.

1. If the app in DomainActivity means can receive push from UA web account at very first time.
2. Following the step 1app will move to User Login page (LoginActivity) , here too can receive pushes from UA web account.
3. Following the step 2 app navigate to Files page ( ThumbActivity) here I can't receive the push messages.

The UA Error console shows "Application does not have permission to send to this device

Original Message: Error: mismatched sender ID"

Note : Without changing the sender ID the steps 1 and 2 working fine but not the 3rd one.

Is anything in Manifest file blocks the push messages?
Is there any permissions I missed?

Note : I am using the trail version.

Comment: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/823114-gcm-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: @dperconti thanks for your support. I am following this guide only for Gcm configuration. Is any other possible ? And is there anything missed in manifest file ?